# An example of a c.i./Gorenstein/C.M. integral domain which is not integrally closed

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, integral-domain

If I am not wrong, it is known that:

{Regular rings} $\subsetneq$ {Complete intersection rings} $\subsetneq$ 
{Gorenstein rings} $\subsetneq$ {Cohen-Macaulay rings}.

It is known that a regular ring is [normal](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Normal_ring) (for example, this result appears in CRT of Matsumura).

I guess there exists a complete intersection/Gorenstein/[Cohen-Macaulay ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Macaulay_ring) (integral domain) which is not normal (integrally closed).

Can one please give an example of a non-local c.i./Gorenstein/C.M. integral domain which is not integrally closed?

Remark: From [Serre's criterion for normality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre%27s_criterion_on_normality), an example I am looking for should NOT satisfy $R_1$.

Comment: Why do you say that an integral domain satisfies $R_1$? For example, does $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3]$ have the $R_1$ property? It is clearly, non-local and a complete intersection.

Comment: If you will check my edits, you will see that I added the last two lines a few minutes after posting the original question, and then deleted them (because I also had $k[x^2,x^3]$ in mind). But thanks anyway for your willingness to help.

Comment: I only know a partial answer to my question; namely, that $k[x^2,x^3]$ is Cohen-Macaulay, but I am not sure I know how to prove that it's c.i. (and knowing it's C.M. was good enough reason for me to delete the last two lines in my question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any singular curve (irreducible and reduced) in the affine plane is clearly a complete intersection, but not normal.

For starters, take $K[x,y]/(x^2-y^3)$.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please add a short explanation why it's an integral domain which is not integrally closed?

Comment: In dimension $1$ integrally closed and regular is the same for a domain.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a "similar" (of course, this is no longer true in higher dimensions) result in higher dimensions? (I am especially interested in dimension $2$), or Serre's criterion for normality is the best we can get? For example, if $R$ is a dimension $2$ C.M. integral domain, is the $R_1$ property can be weakened in some way to a property $\tilde{R_1}$ which implies that $R$ is integrally closed? (Or should I post this last question as a different question?).